# RESTKIT 0.22 CoreData issue on Device

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have a weird issue with restkit mapping to CoreData. All works great in simulator but not in real device. After successful request to server, mapping of results is successful in both  cases (i can access every value in RKMappingResult *mappingResult ). New values are stored in simulator but they arent stored in device. I did a lot of googling but without solution.

I do restkit requst this way:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping =  [[hcUpdateRequest defineUpdateRequestMapping] inverseMapping];

[self.objectManager addRequestDescriptor: [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[hcUpdateRequest class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];

RKEntityMapping *storyMapping = [hcUpdateResponse storyMapping:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];
{..moreMapping..}


[storyMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"pieces" toKeyPath:@"pieces" withMapping:pieceMapping]];
{..moreMapping..}


[self.objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType: RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded];

[self.objectManager postObject:self.dataUpdateRequst
                          path:@"storyAll"
                    parameters:nil
                       success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {…}


+ (RKEntityMapping*) storyMapping:(RKManagedObjectStore*)managedObjectStore {

    RKEntityMapping* storyMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Story" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [storyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"id":@"idRemoteDatabase",
                                                       @"name":@"name",
                                                       @"position_x": @"positionX",
                                                       @"position_y": @"positionY",
                                                       @"state": @"state",
                                                       @"gender": @"gender"
                                                       }];
    storyMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"idRemoteDatabase"];
    return storyMapping;

}
```

Comment: So what is the difference between the device and the sim? Does testing show the same request and responses being sent and received? Stored where? The mappings don't reveal a lot about your problem.

Comment: Yes, simulator and device show the same results. Request and Response are same. The only one difference is that received data isn't stored in CoreData on device. Where to look for the problem? 

CoreData works fine on device when i push them programatically.

Comment: Turn on trace logging, show the code for the core data stack setup.

Comment: Problem was with initialization of object manager 

        NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreData.sqlite"];
        
        [self.objectManager.managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
        
        [self.objectManager.managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

Comment: what problem? Can you make a detail description?